Entity Framework save changes from different Task<T>
My application has two concurrent tasks:
await _fileWatcherService.StartWatchingAsync();
var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueueAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token);

In short StartWatchingAsync is watching a set of folders and notifying when a file is created or edited it updates or insert an entry in my MainDatabase.Sqlite
On the other hand, backgroundTask is receiving some TCP strings and inserting an entry in MainDatabase.Sqlite.
They use different instances of the same context class similar to this
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var existingFile = await context.acquisition_files.FindAsync(acquisition_file.name);

    if (existingFile != null)
    {
        context.Entry(existingFile).CurrentValues.SetValues(acquisition_file);
    }
    else
    {
        await context.acquisition_files.AddAsync(acquisition_file);
    }

    try
    {
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.LogError(ex, $"error saving changes from SaveChangesAsync in FileWatcherService class {ex.Message} AND {ex.InnerException} ");
        Debug.WriteLine($"error saving changes from SaveChangesAsync in FileWatcherService class {ex.Message} AND {ex.InnerException} ");
    }
}

I see in my log file that very often the Exception Database is locked is raised.
I've read that Entity Framework doesn't support saving changes from parallel tasks unless you use different instances of the context (which I do).
How can I solve this issue? Should I have a dedicated database (Mydatabase2) to save changes from the parallel task?

SQLite doesn't deal well with concurrent access, you'd be advised to implement a producer-consumer task which dequeues changes to be made to a single context.
